# Square Dagger: Extending graph properly

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

Let's say I have three Dagger modules:

```
@Module()
public class MainModule {

    private Application application;

    public MainModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    Something provideSomething(Application application) {
        return new Something(application);
    }
}



@Module()
public class SubModule1 {

    private Activity activity;

    public SubModule1(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Activity provideActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides
    SomethingElse provideSomethingElse(Activity activity) {
        return new SomethingElse(activity);
    }
}

@Module()
public class SubModule2 {

    private Activity activity;

    public SubModule2(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Activity provideActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    @Provides
    Anything provideAnything(Activity activity) {
        return new Anything(activity);
    }
}
```

Now assuming I want to do something like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MainModule(this));
        objectGraph.inject(this);
    }
}


public class MyActivity1 extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        objectGraph = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getObjectGraph().plus(new SubModule1(this)
        objectGraph.inject(this);
    }
}


public class MyActivity2 extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        objectGraph = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getObjectGraph().plus(new SubModule2(this)
        objectGraph.inject(this);
    }
}
```

It also might happen that I have such a class:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Inject
    SomethingElse somethingElse;
    @Inject
    Anything anything;
}
```

What is the right way to implement this? How should I use **includes**, **addsTo**, **injects**, **library**, **complete** and **plus()**?

Answer (score 0):

I usually set Dagger up as follows:

Extend Application like this:

```
public class InjectingApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new MainModule(this));
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new SubModule1(this));
        objectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new ActivityModule());
        objectGraph.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Then have a module for adding references to your Activities (called ActivityModule.java in this instance):

```
@Module(
     injects = {
        MyActivity1.class,
        MyActivity2.class }

) public class ActivityModule { }
```

Then your Activities will look like this:

```
public class MyActivity1 extends Activity {

    @Inject
    Something something;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((InjectingApplication) getApplication()).inject(this);
    }

}
```

Finally, your modules will look like this:

```
@Module()
public class MainModule {

    private Context context;

    public MainModule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Provides
    Something provideSomething(Context context) {
        return new Something(context);
    }
}



@Module()
public class SubModule1 {

    private Context context;

    public SubModule1(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides
    SomethingElse provideSomethingElse(Context context) {
        return new SomethingElse(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thanks! But this works only if you replace "Application" and "Activity" by "Context". What if you really need this distinction?

Comment: You can still use "Activity" or "Application" instead of "Context". Typically I've found that I only ever need to pass through the Context, so I used that in the above example

Comment: @Gargamel did that answer your question :)

Comment: Smalesy: Well, thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately my original question hasn't been anwered yet.